# Finding max length of a string + which string it is in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This for HackerRank Weather Observation 5 problem on databases (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-5). How would I solve this?

> Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY
>   names, as well as their respective lengths (i.e.: number of characters
>   in the name). If there is more than one smallest or largest city,
>   choose the one that comes first when ordered alphabetically.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT CITY, MAX LENGTH(CITY) FROM STATION;
```

But it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: where LENGTH(CITY) = (select max(LENGTH(CITY)) from ...

Comment: You should always describe the task in your request. Otherwise, once the site you link to gets out of scope, one cannot not look up the task anymore. I've added a quote from the HackerRank site to describe the task here.

Comment: It seems a bit early for you to set about such a task. You are still struggling to find the longest city name. But the task given asks you to deal with ties (take the first in alphabetical order when the length is the same), which already demands more SQL knowledge. Then you'd not only have to find the longest, but also the shortest city name and show both in one single query. This is not easy. Maybe you should try easier tasks first. I posted my answers, though. They may help others with a similar problem, but I think they won't help *you*, as a beginner, much yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with window functions:

```
select city, length(city)
from
(
  select 
    city, 
    row_number() over (order by length(city), city) as shortest_is_one,
    row_number() over (order by length(city) desc, city) as longest_is_one
  from station
)
where shortest_is_one = 1 or longest_is_one = 1;
```

An alternative would be a `UNION` query with `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`:

```
(
  select city, length(city) 
  from station
  order by length(city), city
  fetch first 1 row only
)
union
(
  select city, length(city) 
  from station
  order by length(city) desc, city
  fetch first 1 row only
);
```

And here is still another query, again using `UNION`:

```
select city, length(city)
from
(
  select max(city) keep (dense_rank first order by length(city), city) as city
  from station
  union
  select max(city) keep (dense_rank first order by length(city) desc, city) as city
  from station
);
```

Comment: @sagi: Well, they are a good way to get the two requested result rows and only read the table once.

Comment: But he doesn't want two, only the longest one, and in this case only one select is enough.

Comment: @sagi: Did you even read the task? `Query the two cities in STATION with the shortest and longest CITY names`.

Comment: Hah, this site is blocked for me, I assumed the task is the title.

Comment: If you use `distinct` and `first_value(city)` instead of `row_number` in the first query you can eliminate the sub-query.

Comment: @Allan: I don't see how `FIRST_VALUE` would get rid of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

In a single table scan:

```
SELECT MIN( city ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) ) AS shortest_city,
       MIN( city ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) ) AS longest_city,
       LENGTH( MIN( city ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) ) )
         AS shortest_length,
       LENGTH( MIN( city ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST  ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) ) )
         AS longest_length
FROM   station;
```

**Explanation**

When using `... KEEP ( DENSE_RANK [FIRST|LAST] ORDER BY ...)` you can read from right-to-left to evaluate what it is doing.

So for:

```
MIN( city ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY LENGTH( city ) )
```

Will:

1. The `ORDER BY` clause orders the results by the length of the city; then
2. The `KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST` clause keeps only the result that is ranked first in the order (and if there are multiple results which are ranked equally first in the order then it will keep all those that are joint first); and, finally,
3. `MIN( city )` will return the minimum value for `city` (i.e. the alphabetically first name) out of the results which where kept (i.e. only those with the shortest length).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. I'm not sure as to performance, but it is working well for me, and not hard to understand. Basically we're just selecting city and the length of the city and storing it in a var 'len_city' and the trick is we list them ascending, but limit the list to one. We then union that answer with the same query, this time, ordering by descending, but also limited to one. This way we get the first shortest and the last longest. I'm open to simpler implementations, but this one is not rocket science, others may be harder to understand but more potent. I'm fairly new to this, but not programming, so, hope this helps!

```
(SELECT city, CHAR_LENGTH(city) AS len_city FROM station ORDER BY len_city ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT city, CHAR_LENGTH(city) AS len_city FROM station ORDER BY len_city DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(select min(city) count(min(city)) from station order by city )
union all
(select max(city) count(max(city)) from station order by city desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT city, CHAR_LENGTH(city) as val1 FROM station order by  CHAR_LENGTH(city) ASC limit 0,1) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT city, CHAR_LENGTH(city) as val2 FROM station order by CHAR_LENGTH(city) DESC limit 0,1)
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more what it does for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

```
select CITY
  , length(CITY)
from station
order by length(CITY), city
limit 1; 

select CITY
  , length(CITY)
from station
order by length(CITY) desc, city
limit 1;
```